# How to make Python openpyxl wait until my worksheet is done fetching data

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file which fetches data from the internet after I have entered a ticker symbol on A1. My problem is that when I open the workbook it won't wait for the data to be downloaded and I will have incorrect values in the cells that I have the formula.

Here is my code so far:

```
def open_excel(symbol):
    book = load_workbook(mySourceExcelFile)
    sheet = book.active
    cellVal = sheet['A1']
    cellVal.value = symbol
    #print(symbol)
    myexcelFilename = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(myCurrentPath), symbol + 'ExcelResult1.xlsx')
    book.save(myexcelFilename)
    book.close()
    files.append(myexcelFilename)
    #print('Cell value updated')
```

Answer (score 0):

The Excel file format does not lend itself to being shared by different applications at the same time so that what you want to do is not possible. You might have more sucess with xlwings.

Comment: @Charlie_Clark
Thank you very much